# Javascript function inside a function -- confused about arguments

Tags: javascript, function

Hi everyone, I'm in the process of learning Javascript and I'm confused about having a function inside another function, in particular the argument part.

I've included a sample code from the lesson where it's looking to calculate the years until retirement for three people given their year of birth.

What I'm confused about is the **year** within the function yearUntilRetirement(name, **year**).

Shouldn't this be **yearOfBirth** instead of **year** since it's looking back at the calculateAge(yearOfBirth) function to find the age? *Or is this argument only unique to the function it is currently in?*

```
function calculateAge(yearOfBirth) {
    var age = 2016 - yearOfBirth;
    return age;
}

function yearsUntilRetirement(name, year) {
    var age = calculateAge(year);
    var retirement = 65 - age;
    console.log(name + ' retires in ' + retirement + ' years.');
}

yearsUntilRetirement('John', 1990);
yearsUntilRetirement('Mike', 1969);
yearsUntilRetirement('Mary', 1948);
```

Comment: argument names dont matter as long as the type is same; for example if year is a string, u will have issues; you can replace year is anything else and still ur code will work fine;

Comment: This is more about consistency. From a language point of view, the name of the variable is determined by the position: the first argument passed `year` is within the scope of the `calculateAge` interpreted as `yearOfBirth`. Naming variables consitently improves understanding.

Comment: You should have a look at scopes (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will clarify.

When you call `yearsUntilRetirement(name, year)`, you pass in two values as the arguments. Such as `yearsUntilRetirement("John", 1975)`. Then, inside of the function `yearsUntilRetirement`, the other function `calculateAge` is called, using the value of `year` as the argument. Since `year` is the value `1975`, we get `age = calculateAge(1975)`. Now, within the `calculateAge` function, the value `1975` is the value corresponding to `yearOfBirth`. So, running everything through, you get `var age = 2016 - 1975`.

If this is too drawn out, I will attempt to clarify further. Drop a comment if you need anything else.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and thank you to everyone who helped me in this literally within minutes after I posted! I only have a vote to give, otherwise I'd give it to all that's helped!

Comment: No problem. Happy coding!